# How to implement Multi-pane layouts

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have a class which extends a `fragment`. In this `Fragment` I need to have `tabs` placed in `vertical` orientation. I have gone through several post but in all it is given how to implement `horizontal tabs` inside a `Fragment`.

My Class:

```
public class Sample extends Fragment {

private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.fragment1);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
            Test.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"),
            Test.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("throttle").setIndicator("Throttle"),
            Test.class, null);

    return mTabHost;
}
}
```

My XML is as follows:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <FrameLayout

        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.3" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >


            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/one"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="tabHandler"
                    android:text="3" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/two"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="tabHandler"
                    android:text="4" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/song_id"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="tabHandler"
                    android:text="5" />
        </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.7" />
</LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

What I get is 3 `tabs` placed horizontally.

Can someone please help me to sort this out. I am not much experienced with `Tabs` Implementation.

Comment: Could someone please help me with this? Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: what you need to do if you don't want to implement horizontal tabs inside a fragment. could you please draw a diagram to explain your GUI

Comment: I want to display something like this:                https://www.google.co.in/search?q=vertical+tabs+in+android&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=677&tbm=isch&imgil=2Jt7F_4DhtHaXM%253A%253BLjtzwsZdXr3EGM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fvenkoolit.blogspot.com%25252F2013%25252F01%25252Fvertical-tabs-in-android.html&source=iu&pf=m&fir=2Jt7F_4DhtHaXM%253A%252CLjtzwsZdXr3EGM%252C_&usg=__Aif8nKUpqVMIMEySWk5WdGwECNk%3D&ved=0CCoQyjdqFQoTCMTs3ovV2scCFVEHjgodWoUL3A&ei=CyLoVYS7DdGOuATaiq7gDQ#imgrc=2Jt7F_4DhtHaXM%3A&usg=__Aif8nKUpqVMIMEySWk5WdGwECNk%3D

Comment: take a look at this while i'm working on your problem http://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/multiple-sizes.html